# Libgdx Desktop project: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdx in java.library.path

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I created Lwjgl libgdx Desktop project in IntelliJ IDEA,
I added and binded the following libraries to /libs:
    gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar,
    gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar,
    gdx-natives.jar,
    gdx.jar.

I got runtime error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdx in java.library.path
for the following line:

```
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(),  "MyGame",MyGame.SCREEN_WIDTH,    MyGame.SCREEN_HEIGHT, false);
```

There was such thread here. They recommended to add *.so files to the project libraries.
But it seems this is obsolete answer.
I can create such project on Eclipse...
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to unpack and place the `.so` files directly under /libs?

Answer (score 0):

You code is right,maybe something is lost.I recommended you use a tool called Gdx Setup UI.

You can find it in office website.